# Bart transformer using HappyTransformer unexpected behaviour in saving the model

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, happytransformer

I have trained a Bart transformer using happytransformer library and when I tested the model after training it gave me 90% accuracy, however when I saved the model and loaded it locally I started to get different outputs and accuracy dropped to 70%, I read that differences in libraries version could cause that problem, so I loaded the model again on google colab to ensure using the same libraries and GPU, however the loaded model still performed differently from the original model.

save code:

```
happy_tt = HappyTextToText("BART", "facebook/bart-large")

args = TTTrainArgs(batch_size=64, num_train_epochs=5)

happy_tt.train("train5.csv", args=args)

happy_tt.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/TransformerModel/model/bart")
```

load code:

```
happy_tt = HappyTextToText("BART", "facebook/bart-large", load_path="/content/drive/MyDrive/TransformerModel/model/bart")
```

any idea what could cause this problem because I have been stuck for days now?